# Diffeomorphism of an open set and almost all of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: measure-theory, diffeomorphism

I am aware of the statement that a open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$, if it is star-like, is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$, although this is apparently not so easy to prove. I am wondering if a weaker statement exists. Namely, if $U$ is an open set of $\mathbb{R}^n$, does there always exist a diffeomorphism $\phi : U\to\mathbb{R}^n\setminus N$ where $N$ is a Lebesgue-negligible set?

Edit: [Here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/4468/what-are-the-open-subsets-of-mathbbrn-that-are-diffeomorphic-to-mathbbr) is a reference the claim that star-shaped open sets are diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: what if $U$ is not connected?

Comment: @mathworker21: I'm not sure that's an obstruction.  For instance $(0,1) \cup (2,3)$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^1 \setminus \{0\}$.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks! So this solves the problem for $n=1$, since any open set is countable disjoint union of open intervals (so, enumerate them and map each diffeomorphically to $(0,1),(-1,0),(1,2),(-2,-1),\dots$). For $n \ge 2$, I think it's true that for any open $U$, we can find a countable collection of disjoint open balls contained in $U$ whose union is $U$ up to measure $0$; then because you can map an open ball diffeomorphically onto a strip (in $\mathbb{R}^2$, e.g., $(0,1)\times\mathbb{R}$), I think we can solve the problem for $U\setminus N'$ for some Lebesgue-null $N'$.

Comment: The question was reposted on Mathoverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/401086/diffeomorphism-of-an-open-set-and-almost-all-of-mathbbrn